# SPARQL to get all parents of all nodes

Tags: rdf, sparql, virtuoso

I have been using this post to get the parents or lineage of a single RDF node:   [SPARQL query to get all parent of a node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17968971/sparql-query-to-get-all-parent-of-a-node)

This works nicely on my virtuoso server.  Sorry, couldn't find a public endpoint containing data with a similar structure.

```
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
prefix bto: <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/>
select (group_concat(distinct ?midlab ; separator = "|") AS ?lineage)
where
{ 
  bto:BTO_0000207 rdfs:subClassOf* ?mid .
  ?mid rdfs:subClassOf* ?class .
  ?mid rdfs:label ?midlab .
}
group by ?lineage
order by (count(?mid) as ?ordercount)
```

giving

```
+---------------------------------------------------------+
|                         lineage                         |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| bone|cartilage|connective tissue|tibia|tibial cartilage |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Then I wondered if I could get the lineage for all nodes by changing the select to**

```
select ?s (group_concat(distinct ?midlab ; separator = "|") AS ?lineage)
```

and the first line in the where statement to

```
?s rdfs:subClassOf* ?mid .
```

Those who have more SPARQL experience than I will probably not be surprised that the query timed out.

**Is this a reasonable approach?  Am I doing something wrong syntactically?**

I suspect that the distinct keyword or group clause are bottlenecks, because this only takes a second or two:

```
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
prefix bto: <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/>
select ?s ?midlab
where
{ 
  ?s rdfs:subClassOf* ?mid .
  ?mid rdfs:subClassOf* ?class .
  ?mid rdfs:label ?midlab .
  ?s <http://www.geneontology.org/formats/oboInOwl#hasOBONamespace> "BrendaTissueOBO"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string> .
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first query isn't legal.  You can check at [sparql.org's query validator](http://sparql.org/query-validator.html).  While you can **order by count(?mid)**, you can't bind the value to a variable and order by it in the same clause.  That would give you:

```sql
select (group_concat(distinct ?midlab ; separator = "|") AS ?lineage)
where
{ 
  bto:BTO_0000207 rdfs:subClassOf* ?mid .
  ?mid rdfs:subClassOf* ?class .
  ?mid rdfs:label ?midlab .
}
group by ?lineage
order by count(?mid)
```

Now, that's *legal*, but it doesn't make quite as much sense.  **group_concat** requires that you have some groups, and that you'll do a concatenation for the values within each group.  In the absence of a **group by** clause, you get an implicit group, so the **group_concat** without a **group by** is OK.  But you've got a **group by ?lineage** that doesn't make a whole lot of sense, because **?lineage** already only has one value per group (since it's already an aggregate). Better would be to **group by ?s**, as in the following.  This seems more correct, and might not time out:

```
select ?s (group_concat(distinct ?midlab ; separator = "|") AS ?lineage)
where
{ 
  ?s rdfs:subClassOf* ?mid .
  ?mid rdfs:subClassOf* ?class .
  ?mid rdfs:label ?midlab .
}
group by ?s
order by count(?mid)
```

Comment: This is looking very promising.  I added a from clause and changed the order by to "(count(?mid) as ?midcount)" and got a reasonable result.

Comment: @MarkMiller `order by (... as ...)` **isn't legal**.  Virtuoso might accept it (it accepts a number of non-standard syntaxes), but it's not legal SPARQL.  If you ever need to run your query against another endpoint, it's very likely that it **won't work**.  You can `select (count(?mid) as ?midcount) { ... } order by ?midcount`, and you can `select ... { ... } order by count(?mid)`, but you can't `select ... { ... } order by (count(?mid) as ?midcount)`.  The variable binding form `(... as ...)` isn't legal in `order by ...`.  (It *is* legal in a `group by`, however.)

Comment: I really appreciate your feedback and apologize for not studying more carefully.  I also use Jena ad am evaluating MarkLogic, so best practices are important to me.  "order by count(?mid)" raised  "Virtuoso 37000 Error SP030: SPARQL compiler, line 12: syntax error at '(' before '?mid'"  Just enclosing it in parentheses without an AS does work and passes the validatior.

Comment: @MarkMiller Yes, Virtuoso's quirks are a semi-constant source of frustration.   Some of the big publicly accessible endpoints (e.g., DBpedia) use endpoint, so it's where a lot of people start, but end up learning some bad habits. :)  It's less common to see *correct* syntax that Virtuoso *doesn't* accept (*incorrect* syntax that *is* accepted is more common), so that **order by** issue is kind of frustrating.   I'm glad you found a workaround (with parentheses), though.