# Find superclasses and sort by distance in SPARQL

Tags: sparql

I'm finding all the superclasses of a type, and all the superclasses of *that* type, and so on all the way up.  I'm doing this using the + operator:

```
SELECT ?superclass WHERE{
    <myType> <superclassPredicate>+ ?superclass
}
```

I would like to get these superclasses back in a reasonable order (eg most specific to least specific).  Is there a way to guarantee this?  I'm familiar with ORDER BY, but I'm not sure what to put into it.

To put it another way: can I keep track of how many "jumps" are made by the + operator?

***EDIT***

It does seems to do this by itself (at least in my implementation), but I'd like to know if this is always the case.

Comment: Have you looked for existing answers? As far as I remember, there are very related questions that have been answered, e.g. if you look for answers by @Joshua Taylor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take the following part of @Joshua Taylor's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17968971/sparql-query-to-get-all-parent-of-a-node) to sort by the number of classes inbetween:

```
prefix : <http://example.org/>
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

select ?class where { 
  :Win7 rdfs:subClassOf* ?mid .
  ?mid rdfs:subClassOf* ?class .
}
group by ?class
order by count(?mid)
```

(@Joshua Taylor)