# Wikidata query for finding presidents

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I was learning the wikidata query language, and wanted to find the US president's name along with grand father, great grand father and so on...

I tried this to get a father, but how to find the father's father and so on...

```
SELECT  ?valLabel ?resLabel
WHERE {
  ?val wdt:P31 wd:Q5.
  ?val  wdt:P27 wd:Q30.
  ?val wdt:P106 wd:Q82955.
  ?val wdt:P22 wd:Q11806.
  OPTIONAL { ?val wdt:P22 ?res. }

  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/blazegraph/database/wiki/RDF_GAS_API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query

```
#Father - GrandFather and so on ...
SELECT  ?childLabel ?fatherLabel ?grandFatherLabel ?greatGrandFather1Label ?greatGrandFather2Label
WHERE {
  ?child wdt:P31 wd:Q5.
  ?child  wdt:P27 wd:Q30.
  ?child wdt:P106 wd:Q82955.
  ?child wdt:P22 wd:Q11806.
  OPTIONAL { ?child wdt:P22 ?father. }
  OPTIONAL { ?father wdt:P22 ?grandFather. }
  OPTIONAL { ?grandFather wdt:P22 ?greatGrandFather1. }
  OPTIONAL { ?greatGrandFather1 wdt:P22 ?greatGrandFather2. }

  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}
```

Comment: How to find the n-th level till it finds no information?

Comment: I don't think we will be able to do that ,as the query will become expensive after some point and it will timeout. What do you want to do with this query ?

Answer (score 1):

Your query is looking for humans who are US citizens who are politicians and whose father is John Adams.

Instead, you want a query like this (in pseudo-SPARQL):

```
SELECT ?presidentLabel ?fatherLabel ?gFatherLabel ?ggFatherLabel ...
WHERE {
?president position_held president_of_the_US .
OPTIONAL{?president has_father ?father .}
OPTIONAL{?father has_father ?gFather .}
OPTIONAL{?gFather has_father ?ggFather .} ...

SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
  }
```

Notice that the optional is necessary, as there may be no information up to the great-grandfather of a president, in which case no information about the president would be returned at all.

In Wikidata, the following should work:

```
SELECT
  ?presidentLabel
  ?fatherLabel
  ?gFatherLabel
  ?ggFatherLabel
WHERE {
  ?president wdt:P39 wd:Q11696.

  OPTIONAL{?president wdt:P22 ?father}
  OPTIONAL{?father wdt:P22 ?gFather}
  OPTIONAL{?gFather wdt:P22 ?ggFather}

  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}
```

However the query seems to time out when you look beyond the president's grandfather.

Bonus: If you want the presidents in chronological order, use this query:

```
 SELECT  ?ord ?presidentLabel ?fatherLabel ?gFatherLabel
 WHERE {
    ?president wdt:P39 wd:Q11696 ;
               p:P39 ?presidency .
    ?presidency ps:P39 wd:Q11696 ;
                pq:P1545 ?ordString .

  OPTIONAL{?president wdt:P22 ?father .}
  OPTIONAL{?father wdt:P22 ?gFather .}

BIND(xsd:integer(?ordString) AS ?ord)      

      
SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
      }
ORDER BY ?ord
```

Comment: How to find the n-th level till it finds no information?

Comment: You will need to use a property path, like this:
?president wdt:P22+ ?ancestor .

This will be slow however, and you need to look at other posts on how to find out what level the ancestor is at.

Comment: See here for inspiration:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31614043/find-superclasses-and-sort-by-distance-in-sparql/31657312#31657312

Answer (score 0):

Here is a query with all fathers (and their fathers, as far back as there is data in Wikidata) of all US presidents:

```
SELECT ?presidentLabel ?fatherLabel 
WHERE 
{
  ?president wdt:P39 wd:Q11696;
             wdt:P31 wd:Q5;
             wdt:P22+ ?father .
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
```

[Try it!](https://w.wiki/Tzg)

Comment: Thanks for the query, learned something new from this, but I wanted to know nth level of father , grandfather and so on for each presidents in a single row.

Comment: As far as I know, that is not possible to do in SPARQL. To get a new column, you need to name the variable, which means that one has to make a decision on the n before querying. (But I must confess this is on the edge of my knowledge and would be happy to be proven wrong.)

Comment: Cool ok, even I am new to this , any way thanks for sharing that query, much helpful :)