# can I do this in AllegroGraph prolog?

Tags: prolog, rdf, sparql, allegrograph

I have an RDF file and I need to extract some information from it in a single line.

Now, I'm using AllegroGraph with Prolog query engin  :

```
(select (?result)
      (q ?a !rdfs:label ?alabel)
      (q ?b !rdfs:label ?blabel)
      (lisp ?result (string+ ?alabel " AND " ?blabel)))
```

to get the results in a single line:

```
 "{a1} AND {b1}" 
 "{a1} AND {b2}" 
 "{a2} AND {b1}" 
 "{a2} AND {b2}"
```

Now, I need to group all the rows of ?result in a single line with the string "OR". so i get:

```
 "{a1} AND {b1} OR {a1} AND {b2} OR {a2} AND {b1} OR {a2} AND {b2}"
```

Is there any function in prolog to do this?

Comment: I don't know whether you can do this in AllegroGraph's Prolog or not, but this can be done relatively easily with a SPARQL 1.1 query.  (This doesn't answer your question, but I expect that AllegroGraph  supports SPARQL 1.1, so you can probably get this result with AllegroGraph, whether in Prolog or not.)

Comment: Thank you. Actually i could'nt find a way to do it in prolog. I guess i will have to get back to SPARQL for the whole project. Can you explain how to do it in SPARQL please.

Comment: Sorry to hear that you didn't find a solution in the Prolog, but now you've got a SPARQL based answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that you've only got `a*` on the left and `b*` on the right means that you've got some other selection condition than just having a label.  Given data like this:

```
@prefix : <http://example.org/>.
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>.

:a1 a :ClassA ; rdfs:label "a1" .
:a2 a :ClassA ; rdfs:label "a2" .
:b1 a :ClassB ; rdfs:label "b1" .
:b2 a :ClassB ; rdfs:label "b2" .
```

you can select `?a` and `?b` by their classes (`:ClassA` and `:ClassB`), and then extract their labels as well, with a pattern like:

```
?a a :ClassA ; rdfs:label ?alabel .
?b a :ClassB ; rdfs:label ?blabel .
```

Then you can get the `{alabel} AND {blabel}` with a `bind` and a `concat`:

```
bind( concat( "{", ?alabel, "} AND {", ?blabel, "}" ) as ?AandB )
```

Using these, a query like

```
prefix : <http://example.org/>
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

select ?AandB { 
 ?a a :ClassA ; rdfs:label ?alabel .
 ?b a :ClassB ; rdfs:label ?blabel .
 bind( concat( "{", ?alabel, "} AND {", ?blabel, "}" ) as ?AandB )
}
```

will get you the kind of results that you can already get:

```
-------------------
| AandB           |
===================
| "{a2} AND {b2}" |
| "{a2} AND {b1}" |
| "{a1} AND {b2}" |
| "{a1} AND {b1}" |
-------------------
```

The trick now is to use `group_concat` and an implicit group to combine all these into a string, with a separator of `" OR "`:

```
prefix : <http://example.org/>
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

select ( group_concat( ?AandB ; separator=" OR ") as ?string ) where { 
 ?a a :ClassA ; rdfs:label ?alabel .
 ?b a :ClassB ; rdfs:label ?blabel .
 bind( concat( "{", ?alabel, "} AND {", ?blabel, "}" ) as ?AandB )
}
```

to get a result:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
| string                                                             |
======================================================================
| "{a2} AND {b2} OR {a2} AND {b1} OR {a1} AND {b2} OR {a1} AND {b1}" |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

If you like, you can even get rid of the `bind`, and just put the `concat` expression right into the `group_concat`.  You might find that easier to read (less jumping around) or harder to read (big one-liner), but at least it's good to have options:

```
prefix : <http://example.org/>
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

select ( group_concat( concat( "{",?alabel,"} AND {",?blabel,"}" ) ; separator=" OR ") as ?string ) where { 
 ?a a :ClassA ; rdfs:label ?alabel .
 ?b a :ClassB ; rdfs:label ?blabel .
}
```

There are some other examples of `group_concat` floating around on StackOverflow that might be useful to you as well:

- [Aggregating results from SPARQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18212697/1281433)
- [RDF list subjects with their objects in a single line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18485461/1281433) (this is actually another question that you asked, and that I answered, and in that answer, I also pointed out the previous question)
- [obtain the matrix in protege](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17924869/1281433) (this does some pretty fancy string manipulation)
- [SPARQL query to get all parent of a node](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17968971/1281433)