# SPARQL property path queries with arbitrary properties

Tags: path, rdf, sparql, semantic-web

[SPARQL property path](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#propertypaths) queries of arbitrary length require using specific properties.  I want to query and find any path starting from a resource and ending in another resource. For example:

```
SELECT ?p
WHERE { :startNode ?p* :endNode }
```

where `?p*` specifies a path. Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: I somehow doubt that is possible with SPARQL (what would `?p` bind to? the SPARQL string that makes up the concrete property path?), and you might want to look at what the [RelFinder](http://www.visualdataweb.org/relfinder.php) people did to find out (more or less) arbitrary connections between two resources.

Comment: You can use wildcards by doing something like `(<>|!<>)*`, which would allows you to find out *whether* there's a path from one place to another, but you can't use variables in property paths.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You're right that you can't use variables in property path expressions. There are a few things that you *can* do, though, that might help you.

## A wildcard to check *whether* a path exists

You can use a wildcard by taking the disjunction of it and its negation, so you can do a simple query that checks *whether* there is a path connecting two resources:

```
<source> (<>|!<>)* <target>
```

If you have a `:` prefix defined, that can be even shorter, since `:` is a valid IRI:

```
<source> (:|!:)* <target>
```

If there is a path (or multiple paths) between two nodes, you can split it up using wildcard paths joined by `?p`, and so find all the `?p`s that are on the path:

```
<source> (:|!:)* ?x .
?x ?p ?y .
?y (:|!:)* <target> .
```

You can make that even shorter, I think, by using blank nodes instead of `?x` and `?y`:

```
<source> (:|!:)* [ ?p [ (:|!:)* <target> ] ]
```

(That *might* not work, though.  I seem to recall the grammar actually disallowing property paths in some places within blank nodes.   I'm not sure.)

## For a single path, get properties and positions, then `group_concat`

Now, in the case that there is just one path between two resources, you can even get the properties along that path, along with their positions.  You could order by those positions, and then use a group by to concatenate the properties in order into a single string.  This is probably easiest to see with an example.  Suppose you've got the following data which has a single path from `:a` to `:d`:

```
@prefix : <urn:ex:> .

:a :p1 :b .
:b :p2 :c .
:c :p3 :d .
```

Then you can use a query like this to get each property in the path and its position.  (This only works if there's a single path, though.  See my answer to [Is it possible to get the position of an element in an RDF Collection in SPARQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17523804/1281433) for a bit more about how this works.)

```sql
prefix : <urn:ex:>

select ?p (count(?mid) as ?pos) where {
  :a (:|!:)* ?mid .
  ?mid (:|!:)* ?x .
  ?x ?p ?y. 
  ?y (:|!:)* :d
}
group by ?x ?p ?y
```

```
-------------
| p   | pos |
=============
| :p2 | 2   |
| :p1 | 1   |
| :p3 | 3   |
-------------
```

Now, if you order those results by `?pos` and wrap *that* query in another, then you can use `group_concat` on `?p` to get a single string of the properties in order.  (The order being preserved isn't guaranteed, but it's pretty common behavior. See my answer to [obtain the matrix in protege](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17924869/1281433) for another example of how this technique works, and [my answer to Ordering in GROUP_CONCAT in SPARQL 1.1](http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/27911/ordering-in-group_concat-in-sparql-11/27967) for discussion about why it is not guaranteed.)

```sql
prefix : <urn:ex:>

select (group_concat(concat('<',str(?p),'>');separator=' ') as ?path) {
  select ?p (count(?mid) as ?pos) where {
    :a (:|!:)* ?mid .
    ?mid (:|!:)* ?x .
    ?x ?p ?y. 
    ?y (:|!:)* :d
  }
  group by ?x ?p ?y
  order by ?pos
}
```

```
-----------------------------------------
| path                                  |
=========================================
| "<urn:ex:p1> <urn:ex:p2> <urn:ex:p3>" |
-----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Why even bother with the empty URI `<>`? Do any triplestore/SPARQL engine combos actually allow this? Fuseki replaces empty URIs with the local URL to the current graph. It seems you could omit the empty URI and just opt for `(!<>)*`

Comment: @Blakeregalia yes, it's very unlikely that it would cause a problem, but sometimes people use uris in strange ways.  Using the alternative gets everything, using the negation gets everything except one.  If you're sure that one isn't used, then the simple negation is fine.