# How to retrieve all resources of a given class connected to a given value

Tags: java, sparql, jena, apache-jena

Is it possible, with a SPARQL query, to retrieve all resources of a given class `C`, in the model connected to a given literal?

For example:

```
S1, p1, o1
S1, type, C
O1, p2, L1

S2, p3, o2
S2, type, C
O2, p4, o3
O3, p5, L1
```

For literal `L1`, I want to retrieve `S1` and `S2`.

Comment: Is it S1,p1,o1 or S1,p1,O1 ? (resp for o2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's always easier if you provide data that we can actually  use.  For instance, here's your data in Turtle, and in a way that we can actually query.  In the future, please try to provide a minimal sample of data that we can use.

```
@prefix : <urn:ex:>

:s1 a :C ;
    :p1 :o1 .

:o1 :p2 "l1" .

:s2 a :C ;
    :p3 :o2 .

:o2 :p4 :o3 .

:o3 :p5 "l1" .
```

Here's a query that finds a path from a subject **?s** that is an instance of **:C** to the literal **"l1"**.  The `(:|!:)*` is a property path using a "wildcard".  Since we've defined the `:` prefix, `:` is an IRI, and since every IRI is either `:` or not (`!:`), a path of zero or more repetitions of `:|!:` is an path from **?s** to **"l1"**. See [SPARQL property path queries with arbitrary properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26698675/sparql-property-path-queries-with-arbitrary-properties) for more about wildcard property paths.

```sql
prefix : <urn:ex:>

select ?s {
  ?s a :C ; (:|!:)* "l1"
}
```

```
-------
| s   |
=======
| :s2 |
| :s1 |
-------
```

Comment: Ohhhh @Joshua thank you so much ... I did not know it. Thank you also for taking the time to explain it :)