# Subproperties in SPARQL query

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I have [this wikidata query](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fcompany%20%3FcompanyLabel%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cen%22.%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%3Fcompany%20%28wdt%3AP127%7Cwdt%3AP749%29%2a%20wd%3AQ7414.%0A%20%20%3Fcompany%20wdt%3AP31%2Fwdt%3AP279%2a%20wd%3AQ4830453.%0A%7D), that tries to find all the companies owned directly or indirectly by the Walt Disney company.

```
SELECT ?company ?companyLabel WHERE {
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
  ?company (wdt:P127|wdt:P749)* wd:Q7414.
  ?company wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q4830453.
}
```

I'm trying to find if company is [owned by](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P749) Disney (P127) or where Disney is the [parent organization](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P749) (P749).

Property P749 is a subproperty of P127. There may be other subproperties of "owned by" that I don't know about.

Can I make a query that returns all companies that has relation that has any subproperty of "owned by" in relation to Disney? I also need to return the subsidiaries of the direct subsidiaries, and the subsidiaries of those subsidiaries and so on.

Comment: Not possible. And even the [ALP service](https://wiki.blazegraph.com/wiki/index.php/PropertyPaths) doesn't support complex conditions like `?edge ^wikibase:directClaim/wd:P1647* wd:P127`. However, `wd:P127` has only three (direct and indirect) subproperties, i.e. you can write something like `(wdt:P127|wdt:P749|wdt:P3931)`.

Comment: I think this is the answer, as I basically have the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26698675/sparql-property-path-queries-with-arbitrary-properties. If you'd like to give this as the answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by means of a recursive property path:

```
?company ?p wd:Q7414.
?p rdfs:subPropertyOf* P:127 .
```

Comment: This responds to my question as I originally asked it. Unfortunately, I need to also get the subsidiaries of the the subsidiaries, and the subsidiaries of those subsidiaries and so on.

Comment: @fgregg then, what prevents you from querying also for the wdt:P355 property of your companies?

Comment: I mean subsidiaries informally here. Orgs that are descendant of other orgs throught an owned_by relation or a subclass of the owned_by relations.

Comment: @fgregg I'm not overly familiar with the Wikidata ontology. You'll have to edit your question to give more specific examples (the properties involved, the expected results, and so on).

Comment: @fgregg I don't get it. What's wrong with `?p rdfs:subPropertyOf* P:127 .` Which in fact returns all subproperties of `owned_by` relation which you then can use as predicate in the triple pattern?

Comment: that part of the query is fine, but then `?company ?p* wd:q7414` does not work. `?company ?p wd:q7414` works, but that only gets me the companies directly owned or controlled, not the companies that are owned or controlled by a company that Disney owns or controls.