# SPARQL property paths

Tags: sparql, propertypath

I have the following RDF data
(Person, worksAt, Branch)
(Branch, location, Town)
(Town, country, Country)

and the property path

```
worksAt, location, country
```

Can I formulate a SPARQL query where given a property e.g. country
it will return me the most-left class (i.e. Person) of the graph?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### without property paths

```
SELECT ?person WHERE
{
  ?person :worksAt ?branch.
  ?branch :location ?town.
  ?town :country :?country.
}
```

### with property paths

Using a *sequence path* [defined as](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-property-paths/):

> elt1 / elt2   A sequence path of elt1, followed by elt2

```
SELECT ?person WHERE
{
  ?person :worksAt/:location/:country ?country.
}
```

I don't understand what you mean with "given a property e.g. country", do you mean a specific instance instead? For example if the person should work in Germany, you would replace `?country` with `:Germany`.

These examples assume that your properties only have a single class as a domain, e.g. only persons can work somewhere. Otherwise you have to add `?person a :Person.` and so on.

Comment: If  I have no idea that ":worksAt" and ":location" properties precede the property of ":country", can I find them using a SPARQL query?  If I find that these are all the previous properties I can also find that the root class of these properties is the class :Person. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @GeorgePerid: According to the SPARQL 1.1 property path specification linked above, variables are not allowed in property paths. However workarounds are described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/26707541/398963.